# Extra Line in Android Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm writting an Android app. I have several spinners. Each one shows an extra line near the bottom and on the left and right sides of the spinner. Please see the image. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image]

Here's the entry in the xml file that defines the spinner:

```
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/formatSpinner"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:prompt="@string/format_prompt"/>
```

And here is the code that initializes it:

```
        cur = mDbHelper.fetchAllFormats();
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cur,
                new String[]{MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        formatSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks!

Update1: I did some experimenting, and if the TextView that precedes the spinner is removed from the XML file, the spinner displays properly. I have no idea why this would be, any ideas?

Update2: Also, if I add a layout_marginTop to the spinner, the problem goes away! This is really weird.

Comment: what is android:drawSelectorOnTop

Comment: Not sure, it doesn't seem to make any difference whether I have it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly a bug with android. I have seen others run into the same issue, and no one has a good answer. This is actually not a line being drawn on the spinner control, as I had originally thought, but a "gap" in the drawing of the control that allows the background color to show through.

The fix, or work around for this is to change the position of where the spinner is drawn. I did this by adding an odd numbered margin before the first spinner. In my case, I used 5dp. I then used 4dp for the following two spinners so that they all begin on an odd pixel number.

This is kind of ugly, but until a fix is created for this, it is the best solution I've found.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/formatSpinner"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:prompt="@string/format_prompt"/>
```

try this..

Comment: Removing the drawSelectorOnTop attribute did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Spinner
    ...            
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    ... />
```